# Sorting a C-style array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm stuck on one part of my assignment. I'm not sure what C-style array exactly is. When I sort a normal array, the sort function works. However, I get a red squiggly in my code where I try to sort the C-style array. Is there something that I'm doing wrong? Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

```
// Goal: To populate a C-style array of 40 million elements with random values between 
    //          1 and 4 billion and then sort via sort() algorithm. Note that you should use the new 
    //          operator to allocate the array.

    // NOTE: The array is created/initialized with with 40 million elements using new operator.

    start_time = time(NULL); // record start time

    {

        size_t *a1 = new size_t[forty_million];

        for (int i = 0; i < forty_million; ++i)
        {
            a1[i] = randomInt(engine);
        }

        sort(a1.begin(), a1.end());

    }

    end_time = time(NULL); // record end time
    total_time = end_time - start_time; // calculate time to compute
    cout << "It took " << static_cast<long>(total_time) << " seconds to compute Part " << part++ << "\n" << endl;
```

Comment: What do you mean "I get a red squiggly", and where exactly do you get that "red squiggly"???

Comment: Does your compiler issue an error when you try to build your code? Just because your IDE says there's an error doesn't mean there actually is one. If you're getting a compiler error you should edit your post and include it there.

Comment: *No, wait... Make that `fifty_million`!*

Comment: Which IDE you are using?

Comment: C++ code is composed of text files, which don't have *colored squigglies*.  If you're asking about colored drawings in your text, your question is really about whatever text editor you're using.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you mean by `red squiggly line`, but my guess is, your IDE highlights a certain part of your code indicating that it may not be correct. Based on your question, my best guess is, your erroneous line is

```
sort(a1.begin(), a1.end());
```

and possibly because `a1` is not a container. This reasoning is seconding on your reference to the terminology `C-Style` array.

`C-style` array is a non standard-library implementation of a homogeneous collection of elements which are contiguous in memory.

Such arrays are not objects in the pure terminology of Object Oriented, and do not have methods (member functions in C++) and properties ( data members in C++).

Naturally, you may not be able to perform method call to fetch the start and end iterators, indicating the begin and end of the array.

Fortunately there are couple of way outs

1. If You are using C++11 and beyond, you can leverage the free standing functions [std::begin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [std::end](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) instead of invoking member functions

   ```
   sort(std::begin(a1), std::end(a1));
   ```
2. If the size of the array is know, you can add to the array to get the end of the array.

   ```
   sort(a1, a1 + sizeof(a1)/sizeof(a1[0]));
   ```

   or even better

   ```
   template < typename Ty, size_t N >
   size_t countof( Ty ( & arr )[ N ] )
   {
        return N;
   } 
   .................
   sort(a1, a1 + N);
   ```

Comment: Perhaps you could introduce your answer by mentioning that the "red squiggly line" probably denotes an error, and work your way from there, adding a "and this is probably what the error message would tell you" somewhere into your current answer...

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: I am not sure, how could I have done that, though I tried my best to give a gentle introduction (see my edit).

Comment: You have a typo at 1), you want `std::begin(a1)`, not `std::begin(a1.begin)`. `std::begin/end` will work only with arrays though, not with pointers.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour _""red squiggly line" probably denotes an error,"_ "red squiggly line" where? What are you mumbling about?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour I'm preferring being unaware of _red squiggly lines_, but certainly not being _"retarded"_.

Comment: Isn't it usually preferred to do `using std::begin; using std::end` rather than using a fully qualified name of an overloaded function?

Comment: @Hurkyl:Off course yes, so that you do not have to encounter unexpected behaviour like OP did. It is better to have a uniform behaviour but then old habits are hard to go.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Then I guess you haven't used many IDEs.